# What's the term (if any) for frameworks that support dynamic class creation?

Tags: reflection, frameworks, terminology, dynamic-class-creation

Sorry about the vocabulary question, but I'm writing my master thesis and it's a pain to repeat "frameworks that support dynamic class creation" again and again. Is there a term for that?

Some clarification: I mean that you can create a class at runtime, i.e., dynamically. For example, .NET supports this with the `System.Reflection` namespace.

Thanks :)

---

Haha, thanks everyone for the suggestions. I'm not going to pick an answer yet in case there *is* a term for this and someone finds it, but if there isn't I'll definitely make one up. Thanks. :)

Comment: You totally can create your own, which is the beauty of a thesis or any academic paper for that matter.  And better yet, make it something fun, like FATDAC (FrAmeworks That support DynAmic Class creation).  although, you might want to come up with something that is a little better than that... ;-) Of course...if there is a term for it, you'd be better off using it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DCC Framework, Invent an acronym.

Comment: I quite like this one. If no one gives me the "real" name I'll go with this one. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamic class creation is covered by the term "[metaprogramming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming)", although metaprogramming includes more than that.

Comment: Runtime dynamism is a more specific term, but it's referring to the technique rather than the framework.

Answer (score 1):

It's more the development language rather than framework

A reflective programing language enables the determination of object type at runtime. Most (if not all) include some sort of class loading mechanism to dynamically create objects at runtime as a result.

You could try...

> Reflective Framework?
>
> Introspective Frameworks?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions (and you're right about language vs. framework, I keep making that mistake). However, I don't know if I agree with your second statement: as I understand it a reflective programming language is able to observe its own structure and/or behaviour, but does that mean that it gives you the tools to create a new class at runtime? Not necessarily. I don't know if they usually do, but it's not necessarily related. Or does the term "reflective programming language" impose other requirements on the language? I may be mistaken.